# How to use a function from a second C file in the main C file?

Tags: c, function, syntax, header-files

I'm trying to split up a large C file because it's very difficult to read and keep track of what's doing what. I read up on it and it supposed to be as simple as creating a c file that contains the function, then a header file that references the function, then include the header file in main c file and simply use the function. However, I've done that and the function in question isn't actually being called in my code.

I tried placing printf statements in the function so I could see if it was really being called and these do not show up in monitor (which I interpret as the function is not being called)

```
//MAIN.c
#include "just_printf.h"

void app_main(){
    printf("attempting to call print\n");
    just_print();
}

//---------------------------------------
//JUST_PRINTF.h
#ifndef MAIN_JUST_PRINT_H_
#define MAIN_JUST_PRINT_H_

void just_print();

#endif

//---------------------------------------
//JUST_PRINTF.c
#include "just_printf.h"

void just_print(){
    printf("tried to prrint");
}
```

When I run main.c, it's supposed to print "attempting to call print" then when it calls just_print() it's supposed to print "tried to prrint". This is just a sanity check before I try moving actual functionality out of my main.c file. What am I doing wrong? Am I misunderstanding how to split up a c file? Right now all I get is the first printf statement before the function call.

Comment: What *do* happen when you run the program? What is the output you *do* get? Please take some to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Fix your casing in your file names so that it matches your includes.

Comment: https://repl.it/@robertwharvey/Just-Print

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In main.c, change:

```
void app_main() {
```

to:

```
int main(void) {
```

and then compile like:

> gcc main.c just_printf.c

and the output will be (after executing a.out):

```
Georgioss-MBP:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
attempting to call print
tried to prrint
```

You should get a warning about implicit declaration of the function printf, since you don't include `stdio.h` - do that in the header file, I would suggest, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Suggestion: In the header file, the include guard would be usually written like:

```
JUST_PRINT_H
```

i.e., without the trailing underscore, and the full name of the file, in capital characters.